# compiler error if MFC RUNTIME_CLASS argument has namespace

Tags: c++, mfc, compilation

I've got the answer, see bottom.

NOTE: "_AFXDLL" is not predefined for my case, linking statically to MFC.

I have code like this:

MyClass.h

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class CMyClass : public CMyBase
    {
        DECLARE_DYNAMIC( CMyClass )
        ...
    }
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
using namespace MyNameSpace;
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC( CMyClass , CMyBase)
```

caller

```
CMyBase* pObject = new MyNameSpace::CMyClass();
....
pObject->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(MyNameSpace::CMyClass))
```

When compile, I've got error:

```
error C3083: 'classMyNameSpace': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
error C2277: 'MyNameSpace::CMyClass::{ctor}' : cannot take address of this member function
```

I investigated the macro RUNTIME_CLASS and found that it eventually expanded to:

```
#define RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name) _RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name)
#define _RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name) ((CRuntimeClass*)(&class_name::class##class_name))

(CRuntimeClass*)(&MyNameSpace::CMyClass::classMyNameSpace::CMyClass)
```

Ideally, if it can expand to following code, then all good.

```
(CRuntimeClass*)(&MyNameSpace::CMyClass::classCMyClass)
```

**Now my question:**

1. Is this a known issue from microsoft that "we can not use namespace in RUNTIME_CLASS"?
2. A more practical question: For some reason(e.g. Classes from different namespace conflict), we can not "using namespace" in cpp file, how can we use Runtime Type Identification in MFC?

**Answer** from Hans Passant:

Microsoft has confirmed this bug [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/180980/namespaces-do-not-work-with-runtime-class-macro-in-static-builds#).

**The workaround is quite smart, I copied it here:**

```
Posted by BongoVR on 8/15/2006 at 2:39 AM
define YET ANOTHER MACRO and use it instead of RUNTIME_CLASS when namespace-qualified class names are to be used in the code:
#ifdef _AFXDLL
#define RUNTIME_CLASS_N(n, class_name) (n::class_name::GetThisClass())
#else
#define RUNTIME_CLASS_N(n, class_name) ((CRuntimeClass*)(&n::class_name::class##class_name))
#endif
```

This macro works in both builds (_AFXDLL defined and not defined).

Comment: Is `CMyClass` actually in `MyNamespace`? If it is, why not show it in the code?

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, it is. Modified the code

Comment: Pürobably not the cause but isn't there a '{' missing  before "namespace MyNameSpace" in MyClass.h.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It is just a typo, corrected, problem still exists.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/180980/namespaces-do-not-work-with-runtime-class-macro-in-static-builds

Comment: I think most programmers will just follow the advice given in the feedback article and avoid static linking.  You put your own spin on it so you are best qualified to answer this question.  Just mark your post as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer from Hans Passant:**

Microsoft has confirmed this bug here.

The workaround is quite smart, I copied it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/180980/namespaces-do-not-work-with-runtime-class-macro-in-static-builds#):

```
Posted by BongoVR on 8/15/2006 at 2:39 AM
define YET ANOTHER MACRO and use it instead of RUNTIME_CLASS when namespace-qualified class names are to be used in the code:
#ifdef _AFXDLL
#define RUNTIME_CLASS_N(n, class_name) (n::class_name::GetThisClass())
#else
#define RUNTIME_CLASS_N(n, class_name) ((CRuntimeClass*)(&n::class_name::class##class_name))
#endif
```

This macro works in both builds (_AFXDLL defined and not defined).

Answer (score 0):

The MFC macros can be limited, how about using dynamic_cast instead of IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name))?

```
CMyBase* pObject =dynamic_cast<MyNameSpace::CMyClass>(new MyNameSpace::CMyClass);
```